# Change all row values in a window pyspark dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe which has three columns id, seq, seq_checker. I need to order by id and check for 4 consecutive 1's in seq_checker column.

I tried using window functions. I'm unable to change all values in a window based on a condition.

`new_window = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("id").rangeBetween(0, 3)`
`output = df.withColumn('check_sequence',F.when(F.min(df['seq_checker']).over(new_window) == 1, True))`

original pyspark df:

```
+---+---+-----------+--------------+
| Id|seq|seq_checker|check_sequence|
+---+---+-----------+--------------+
|  1|  1|          1|         false|
|  2|  2|          1|         false|
|  3|  3|          1|         false|
|  4|  4|          1|         false|
|  5| 10|          0|         false|
|  6| 14|          1|         false|
|  7| 13|          1|         false|
|  8| 18|          0|         false|
|  9| 23|          0|         false|
| 10|  5|          0|         false|
| 11| 56|          0|         false|
| 12| 66|          0|         false|
| 13| 34|          1|         false|
| 14| 35|          1|         false|
| 15| 36|          1|         false|
| 16| 37|          1|         false|
| 17| 39|          0|         false|
| 18| 54|          0|         false|
| 19| 68|          0|         false|
| 20| 90|          0|         false|
+---+---+-----------+--------------+
```

Required output:

```
+---+---+-----------+--------------+
| Id|seq|seq_checker|check_sequence|
+---+---+-----------+--------------+
|  1|  1|          1|          true|
|  2|  2|          1|          true|
|  3|  3|          1|          true|
|  4|  4|          1|          true|
|  5| 10|          0|         false|
|  6| 14|          1|         false|
|  7| 13|          1|         false|
|  8| 18|          0|         false|
|  9| 23|          0|         false|
| 10|  5|          0|         false|
| 11| 56|          0|         false|
| 12| 66|          0|         false|
| 13| 34|          1|          true|
| 14| 35|          1|          true|
| 15| 36|          1|          true|
| 16| 37|          1|          true|
| 17| 39|          0|         false|
| 18| 54|          0|         false|
| 19| 68|          0|         false|
| 20| 90|          0|         false|
+---+---+-----------+--------------+
```

Based on the above code, my output is:

```
+---+---+-----------+--------------+
| Id|seq|seq_checker|check_sequence|
+---+---+-----------+--------------+
|  1|  1|          1|          true|
|  2|  2|          1|          null|
|  3|  3|          1|          null|
|  4|  4|          1|          null|
|  5| 10|          0|          null|
|  6| 14|          1|          null|
|  7| 13|          1|          null|
|  8| 18|          0|          null|
|  9| 23|          0|          null|
| 10|  5|          0|          null|
| 11| 56|          0|          null|
| 12| 66|          0|          null|
| 13| 34|          1|          true|
| 14| 35|          1|          null|
| 15| 36|          1|          null|
| 16| 37|          1|          null|
| 17| 39|          0|          null|
| 18| 54|          0|          null|
| 19| 68|          0|          null|
| 20| 90|          0|          null|
+---+---+-----------+--------------+
```

Edit:
1. If we have more than 4 consecutive rows having 1's we need to change check_sequence flag for all the rows to True.

2. My actual problem is to check for sequences of length greater than 4 in the 'seq' column. I was able to create seq_checker column using lead and lag functions.

Comment: How do you treat 5 consectutive 1's?

Comment: Need 5 consecutive true's.

Answer (score 0):

Initially define a window with just an `id` ordering. Then use a difference in row numbers approach (with different ordering) to group consecutive 1's (also groups consecutive same values) with the same group number. Once the grouping is done, just check to see if the `max` and `min` of the group is 1 and there are atleast 4 1's in the group, to get the desired `boolean` output.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number,count,when,min,max
w1 = Window.orderBy(df.id)
w2 = Window.orderBy(df.seq_checker,df.id)
groups = df.withColumn('grp',row_number().over(w1)-row_number().over(w2))
w3 = Window.partitionBy(groups.grp)
output = groups.withColumn('check_seq',(max(groups.seq_checker).over(w3)==1) & (min(groups.seq_checker).over(w3)==1) & (count(groups.id).over(w3) >= 4)
output.show()
```

Comment: Your code contains some invalid syntax. Could your please check it again?

Comment: You also have to `max(seq_checker)` to `max(df.seq_checker)`, otherwise the interpreter will not be able to resolve the reference.

Comment: Now it is working, but it only fetches the first group consectutive 1's and not the second group.

Comment: `groups.withColumn` is missing the right parenthesis, but the result is correct now.

Answer (score 0):

The [rangeBetween](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window.rangeBetween) gives you the access to rows which are relative from the current row. You defined a window for 0,3 which gives you access to the current row and the three following rows, but this will only set the correct value for the first 1 of 4 consectutive rows of 1's. The second element of 4 consectutive rows of 1's needs acess to the previous row and following two rows (-1,2). The third element of 4 consectutive rows of 1's needs acess to the two previous rows and following two rows (-2,1). Finally the fourth element of 4 consectutive rows of 1's needs acess to the three previous rows(-3,0).

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

l = [
(  1,  1,          1),
(  2,  2,          1),
(  3,  3,          1),
(  4,  4,          1),
(  5, 10,          0),
(  6, 14,          1),
(  7, 13,          1),
(  8, 18,          0),
(  9, 23,          0),
( 10,  5,          0),
( 11, 56,          0),
( 12, 66,          0),
( 13, 34,          1),
( 14, 35,          1),
( 15, 36,          1),
( 16, 37,          1),
( 17, 39,          0),
( 18, 54,          0),
( 19, 68,          0),
( 20, 90,          0)
]

columns = ['Id','seq','seq_checker']

df=spark.createDataFrame(l, columns)

w1 = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("id").rangeBetween(0, 3)
w2 = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("id").rangeBetween(-1, 2)
w3 = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("id").rangeBetween(-2, 1)
w4 = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("id").rangeBetween(-3, 0)

output = df.withColumn('check_sequence',F.when(
                                            (F.min(df['seq_checker']).over(w1) == 1) |
                                            (F.min(df['seq_checker']).over(w2) == 1) |
                                            (F.min(df['seq_checker']).over(w3) == 1) |
                                            (F.min(df['seq_checker']).over(w4) == 1) 
                        , True).otherwise(False))
output.show()
```

Output:

```py
+---+---+-----------+--------------+ 
| Id|seq|seq_checker|check_sequence| 
+---+---+-----------+--------------+ 
|  1|  1|          1|          true| 
|  2|  2|          1|          true| 
|  3|  3|          1|          true| 
|  4|  4|          1|          true|          
|  5| 10|          0|          null| 
|  6| 14|          1|          null| 
|  7| 13|          1|          null| 
|  8| 18|          0|          null| 
|  9| 23|          0|          null| 
| 10|  5|          0|          null| 
| 11| 56|          0|          null| 
| 12| 66|          0|          null| 
| 13| 34|          1|          true| 
| 14| 35|          1|          true| 
| 15| 36|          1|          true| 
| 16| 37|          1|          true| 
| 17| 39|          0|          null| 
| 18| 54|          0|          null| 
| 19| 68|          0|          null| 
| 20| 90|          0|          null| 
+---+---+-----------+--------------+
```